# String reader only work 1 time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, stringreader

I am working on a small test project where 99.9% of the game is in the code and 0.1% is with the visual editor.

I am creating tile map for some sort of Tower Defence.
each map is 5/5 and are loaded from a text file in the resources folder

i dont understand why but it only work 1 time. 
if i try to build 2 map or build 1, destroy it and rebuild it i get this error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   MapBuilder.buildMap (UnityEngine.GameObject parent, .Map map) (at >Assets/script/MapBuilder.cs:21)
>   Map.build (System.String _name) (at Assets/script/Map.cs:39)
>   Main.Start () (at Assets/script/Main.cs:20)

my main class (only creating maps for test at the moment)

```
public class Main : MonoBehaviour {
GameObject mainObject;

Map map;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    mainObject = GameObject.Find("Main");

    map = gameObject.AddComponent<Map>();

    map.build("map_start");

    GameObject map2 =  GameObject.Find("map_start1");

    Map map2C = map2.AddComponent<Map>();

    map2C.build("map_start1");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

my map class

```
public class Map : MonoBehaviour {

public List<GameObject> planes;

public List<List<int>> mapData;

public string mapName;


public void build(string _name)
{
    mapName = _name;
    if(planes != null)
    {
        delete();
    }
    else
    {
        planes = new List<GameObject>();

        mapData = new List<List<int>>();
    }
    MapBuilder.buildMap(gameObject, gameObject.GetComponent<Map>());

}

private void delete()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < planes.Count; i++)
    {
        Destroy(planes[i]);
    }

    mapData.Clear(); //do not clear capacity! only clear element (avoid     reallocating the memory)

    planes = new List<GameObject>();

    mapData = new List<List<int>>();
}
```

}

and here is the part where i have the bug

```
    public const float height = -2;

public static Map buildMap(GameObject parent, Map map)
{       
    //get the stream reader ready
    FileInfo sourceFile = null;
    StringReader reader = null;

    Debug.Log(map.mapName);
    //load
    TextAsset mapDataStream = (TextAsset)Resources.Load(map.mapName,  typeof(TextAsset));
    //Debug.Log(mapDataStream.text);
    //read
    reader = new StringReader(mapDataStream.text);

    for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        string txt = reader.ReadLine();

        map.mapData.Add(new List<int>());

        //get height data
        for(int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
        {
            map.mapData[x].Add(0);
            map.mapData[x][y] = 49 - txt[y];

        }
    }

    mapDataStream = null;
    reader.Close();
```

the error is at this exact line:
    reader = new StringReader(mapDataStream.text);

It ask a lot more knowledge to do the game without using the editor and i learned a lot so far.
But this is the first bug i did not find a solution by myself

this is what a map look like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouGMr.png

(need 10 reputation to inline the image)

i get the data from a text file who look like this:
00000
11111
00000
11011
11111

and i create the mesh myself (primitive plane have 2 triangle per unit and modifying them would be to much for nothing, mine have 2 triangles)

there is no texture so far. this will be added later

the player will be able to build his own maps to defend. He will be able to add a set number of maps of many form and he will be able to rotate them and etc...
the next step will be to add the pathfinding to validate the map set by the player.

thanks for your help

Comment: Can you please debug your application and determine if mapDataStream is null or if the text property is null?

Regardless, my first guess is that you are maintaining a lock on the map and can't read it a second time.

Comment: i dont know why but my debogger seems broken and i cant get step by step froma  breakpoint.

Comment: i added a Log in case it was null and yeah at the second time i build a map, mapDataStream is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the following line:

`TextAsset mapDataStream = (TextAsset)Resources.Load(map.mapName,  typeof(TextAsset));`

By debugging your code; step through the code line by line. Determine if `mapDataStream` is ever `NULL` because if it is, the next line of code will throw a `NullReferenceException` because you attempt to read a property of a null object.

In Mono you can follow their guide for debugging to easily step through your code and identify problems. Refer to this link https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Debugger.html

Its as simple as putting a break point on the line you wish to debug:

1. Open your project in Mono Develop.
2. hit play in the Unity Editor.
3. In Mono Develop select run attach to process... and select unity editor.
4. You can now use breakpoints in Mono Develop and step through code, watch variables, etc.

Here is a video to help you understand this better:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-D6qXaGSC2k

Comment: mono was bugged for some reason and closing and opening back everything fixed mono.

Comment: as i can see the second time i load the map, mapDataStream is null. no matter what map i load. If i load 2 time the first map it dont work

Comment: wow i am not proud of me this time. i noticed there was a space in the name of the second map. my code was ok all the time.
This is the kind of stupidity that make me want to throw everything.

NVM and sorry for wasting your time. thanks aniway

Comment: @CédricRaymond It happens, at least you got the debugger to work ;)

Comment: There is positive in everything